# How can I create remote repository from local system without creating a repository directly from github portal?

Tags: git, ssh-agent, git-init

I am a newbie at Git. I am still learning.

Here are the steps that I have taken in order to create the repository so far:

1. Navigated to the directory that is going to be associated with the repository.
2. Ran the command: `git init`
3. Then I checked the status of all the untracked files using the command: `git status`
4. I needed to commit all the files so I added all to the staged files using the command: `git add .`
5. I committed the code using the command: `git commit -m "Initial Commit"`
6. Then I tried to push the code using the command: `git push --set-upstream origin master`
7. Since the remote is not set yet, I faced the error: `fatal: No configured push destination.`

After the facing the above error, I tried to add the remote using the command:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:username/repo-name
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

After hitting the above commands, I faced the error:

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (IP)' can't be established.
```

So I tried to create an SSH key as suggested in [this link](https://help.github.com/en/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent). The SSH key was created successfully, but when I tried to add my SSH key to the ssh-agent using the following commands:

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
```

I encountered the following error:

```
'eval' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

I also tried to execute `ssh-agent -s` directly, but then I encountered the following error:

```
unable to start ssh-agent service, error :1058
```

I googled the issue and found [this link](https://github.com/lukesampson/pshazz/issues/70). I tried to use the following commands:

```
> Set-Service ssh-agent -StartupType Manual
> install-sshd.ps1
```

But both have given me the following errors respectively:

```
> 'Set-Service' is not recognized as an internal or external command
> 'install-sshd.ps1' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

By the way I am using Windows 10.

What should I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and create an SSH key, for testing, without passphrase: you won't need an ssh-agent then.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM -P"" -C "your@email.com"
```

Copy the `%USERNAME%\.ssh\id_rsa.pub` content [to GitHub account](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.15/user/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account).

[Test it](https://help.github.com/en/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection) with `ssh -T git@github.com` (type 'yes' if it asks you)

Finally, try your `git push -u origin master` again.

Note... you still need to [create an empty GitHub repo first on GitHub side](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-new-repository).